# dynamic image slider into dynamic cards in asp.net mvc c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I want to display cards in my home page this cards content image slider.
ex: card contains Toyota cars information and slider for cars images. 
another card to display BMW cars information and slider for cars images.
I already have the database and model and my code run perfectly with one card only when I enter two or more cards it doesn't work(the images appear only in the first card).

here is my code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BrokenCar)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <h3 class="card-header">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h3>
                <form id="form1">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div id="container">
                            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DescriptionEn)</p>
                            <div id="banner-fade">
                                <ul class="bjqs">
                                    @foreach (var image in Model.BrokenCarImage.Where(o => o.BrokenCarID.Equals(item.BrokenCarID)))
                                    {
                                        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(image.BrokenCarImg);
                                        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                                        <li>
                                            <img src='@imgsrc' title='@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)' alt="">
                                        </li>
                                    }
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <script src="../assets/js/libs/jquery.secret-source.min.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            jQuery(function ($) {

                                $('.secret-source').secretSource({
                                    includeTag: false
                                });

                                $('#banner-fade').bjqs({
                                    height: 320,
                                    width: 620,
                                    responsive: true
                                });
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                    2 days ago
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    }
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  (At a quick glance it looks like you're at least duplicating `id` values in your HTML, which is invalid.)

Comment: the images appear only in the first card

Comment: @David thanks it works after making the id dynamic

Answer (score 0):

it works after I replaced the static id `<div id="banner-fade">` with dynamic id `<div id='@item.BrokenCarID'>`
also updated it in the script `$('#@item.BrokenCarID')`